# Show value into combo box using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

my problem is how to append data to the combo box, meanwhile there are 2 value in controller

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    $(document).ready(function(){
                                        $('#bill').change(function(){
                                            var bill = $(this).val();
                                                $.ajax({
                                                url:'<?=$url?>/bill',
                                                method: 'get',
                                                data: {bill: bill},
                                                success: function(data)
                                                {   
                                                    $("#period").html(data."#test");
                                                    $("#period").val(data);
                                                    $("#appen").html(data);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
<select name="periode" required class="form-control select2 txtx" >
                                            <option value="">Select Period</option>
                                            <option value="" id="period" selected></option>
                                        </select>
<div id="appen"></div>
```

in my controller

```
echo "<a id='test'>test</a>" // i need this to append in combo box
echo "<a>test number 2 </a>" //i need this to append in tag <div>
```

Comment: the first value do you want to pass as text or value in select dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I made some changes according to your need
Controller:

> here I created one array which will echo your `JSON` and to terminate script I wrote `exit();`

```
function yourMethodName($bill){
    //do something with $bill
    $response_array['comboBox'] = "<a id='test'>test</a>";;
    $response_array['divBox'] = '<a>test number 2 </a>';
    echo json_encode($response_array);
    exit();
}
```

Ajax:

> first thing if you are using `GET` then you can pass as `data` or as `parameter` you passed both so keep it only one of them so here, i removed `data` and pass as `parameter`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bill').change(function(){
            var bill = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo $url;?>/'+bill,
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {   
                    $("#period").html(data.comboBox);
                    $("#appen").html(data.divBox);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why -1 ? can anyone tell me which thing makes it to get -1

Answer (score 1):

You should return data to AJAX as JSON like this :

**IN your controller**

```
$return['comboBox'] = "<option value='test'>test</option>";
$return['divBox'] = '<a>test number 2 </a>';

return json_encode($return);
```

**IN AJAX success function**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bill').change(function(){
            var bill = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                url:'<?=$url?>/bill',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {bill: bill},
                success: function(data)
                {   
                    $("select").append(data.comboBox);
                    $("#appen").html(data.divBox);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it return empty, i tried $("select").append(data.comboBox); but nothing i change to the id it still empty

Comment: Maybe you should parse JSON before can use it, add that line before append select `data = JSON.parse(data);`. If it still not working, please post your data `console.log` here